# NetBeans, JNLP, and ServiceManager permissions

Tags: java, netbeans, java-web-start, jnlp

I am developing a JNLP (Java Web Start) app in NetBeans.  When I press "Run", the JFrame opens and everything works great.

Now I am adding a feature.  The user must be able to choose a local file.  I understand that I should use this technique:

```
ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.FileOpenService")
```

When I add this line to my main class and press "Run", I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jnlp/UnavailableServiceException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2937)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1771)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jnlp.UnavailableServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

How can I use the file service during local testing?

It *does* work when I build the JAR, upload it to the web, and manually run the JNLP.  What is a better work flow for NetBeans?

Comment: See [Enabling Java Web Start in the NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/javase-jws.html).

Comment: I followed those steps exactly and it still is not working.  Does this actually work for you?